# How to remove Exif,IPTC,XMP data of a png image in Java

Tags: java

We are trying to remove Exif,IPTC and XMP data for png image. Please provide sample code for same

1. We are having a png image file.
2. Need to remove Exif,IPTC and XMP data.

> ```
> package com.test;
>
> import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
> import java.io.File;
> import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
> import java.io.FileOutputStream;
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.io.OutputStream;
>
> import org.apache.commons.imaging.ImageReadException;
> import org.apache.commons.imaging.ImageWriteException;
> import org.apache.commons.imaging.formats.jpeg.iptc.JpegIptcRewriter;
>
> class ImageUploadTest {
>
>   public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>       try {
>
>           final File original = new File(
>                   "/Users/anupam256093/Downloads/Test.png");
>           final File newimage = new File(
>                   "/Users/anupam256093/Downloads/Test_resized2.png");
>           removeExifTag(original, newimage);
>
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
>           System.out.println(e);
>       }
>
>   }
>
>   public static void removeExifTag(final File jpegImageFile, final File dst) {
>       OutputStream os = null;
>       OutputStream osiptc = null;
>
>       try {
>           System.out.println("4");
>
>           os = new FileOutputStream(dst);
>           os = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
>           System.out.println("15");
>           osiptc = new FileOutputStream(dst);
>           osiptc = new BufferedOutputStream(osiptc);
>           new JpegIptcRewriter().removeIPTC(jpegImageFile, os);
>           // new ExifRewriter().removeExifMetadata(jpegImageFile, os);
>           System.out.println("15");
>
>           //new PngWriter(true).writeImage(jpegImageFile, os, null);
>           //System.out.println("16");
>
>           os.close();
>           os = null;
>           System.out.println("7");
>
>           System.out.println("SUCCESS");
>       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
>           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>           System.out.println("ERROR");
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       } catch (ImageWriteException e) {
>           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>           System.out.println("ERROR1");
>
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       } catch (IOException e) {
>           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>           System.out.println("ERROR2");
>
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       } catch (ImageReadException e) {
>           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       } finally {
>           if (os != null) {
>               try {
>                   os.close();
>               } catch (final IOException e) {
>
>               }
>           }
>       }
>   }
>
> }
> ```

We are trying to remove Exif,IPTC and XMP data for png image. Please provide sample code for same

1. We are having a png image file.
2. Need to remove Exif,IPTC and XMP data.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062959/how-to-remove-image-metadata-from-large-images-without-out-of-memory-in-java

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("input.png"));
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("output.png"));
```

Comment: It will not remove Exif,IPTC and XMP data in newly generated image.

Comment: It will remove everything that is not needed to read the image

Comment: Now problem is that it increase size of the image. We want the same size in KB whatever is earlier.

Comment: Yeah, I think it writes png24 files. I don't know if you can control that.