# How to remove EXIF content from a image file of TIFF,PNG using a Java API

Tags: java

I'm using `apache-commons-sanselan.jar` API to remove `EXIF` content from only `JPEG` file.

How to remove this content from other file extensions?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37062959/how-to-remove-image-metadata-from-large-images-without-out-of-memory-in-java

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));  
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("image.jpg"));
```

Metadata isn't read when you read an image. Just write it back. Replace `jpg` with the extension you want.

Sources:
[How to remove Exif,IPTC,XMP data of a png image in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201026/how-to-remove-exif-iptc-xmp-data-of-a-png-image-in-java)
[How can I remove metadata from a JPEG image in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666999/how-can-i-remove-metadata-from-a-jpeg-image-in-java)

Comment: For JPG, wouldn't this recompress the image (and likely degrade it a little)?

Comment: How heavy approach it would be if we need to modify hundreds of images (though in background thread or so)...

Answer (score -1):

In addition to [@little-child](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1894684/little-child) answer

code:

```
public static void removeExifTag(final String sourceImageFile, final File destinationImageFile) throws IOException, ImageReadException, ImageWriteException {
    try (
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationImageFile);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ){
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(sourceImageFile));
        originalImage.flush();
        ImageIO.write( originalImage,"jpg", baos );
        byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
        new ExifRewriter().removeExifMetadata(imageInByte, bos);
        baos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ImageReadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ImageWriteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Comment: doesn't works with png images cus it throws 
org.apache.commons.imaging.ImageReadException: Not a Valid JPEG File: doesn't begin with 0xffd8

Comment: what are the arguments you are passing to .write method of `ImageIO` object?

Comment: "png", but this is working actually the line that is broken is          

 ```new ExifRewriter().removeExifMetadata(imageInByte, bos);```

but if working actually your code is faster that the one of @Little Child