# How to remove image metadata from large images without out of memory in Java

Tags: java

I need to remove metadata from images but when images are too large I get OOM.
Right now I'm using ImageIO for that.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File("image.jpg"));
```

Problem is that *ImageIO.read(...)* will read the whole file into memory, which causes OutOfMemory when I'm processing images that are too big.

I could try using CommonsImaging (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/sampleusage.html) but looks like it supports only JPEG (ExifRewriter class).

Changing the memory config for the VM is not an option and I need to support more than just JPEG files.

Any ideas how to do that without incurring into Out of Memory?

Comment: How much is the RAM of the machine where you are running this code? And what is the size of the image?

Comment: Are you running your program in IDE? Have you ever tried running it out of IDE?

Comment: Even if there was enough memory, the recompression would likely reduce image quality as well. An API to just work on the metadata would really be better.

Comment: @user2864740: How do you close a `File` object? And why? It's just a wrapper around a String.

Comment: @Siddharth: The image is about 100MB, something around 20000 x 20000.

Comment: @kenshinji I am not running it in IDE. This is a service running on a separate host. The host has enough memory, but the JVM is dying. As I said, I cannot change the size of JVM heap. I'm looking for a solution that would preferably use buffers of fixed size, so I would not have everything in memory.

Answer (score -1):

You could try it by making a copy of the image via streaming and during the streaming apply a filter to remove the metadata.

The copying could be done as follows:

```
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        // Source and Destination must be different 
        is = new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/img/src"));
        os = new FileOutputStream(new File("path/to/img/dest"));

        // Limit buffer size further is necessary!
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            // Apply removal of metadata here!!!
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    } finally {
        is.close();
        os.close();
    }
```

Note that the original and clone can't be the same so it might be necessary to delete the original and rename the destination file afterwards (if you want to the them the same).

Instead of a normal `outputstream` you could also create your own `FilteredOutputstream` and use that instead.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that each image has its own way of storing metadata and having this logic applied here would make the code too complex. I would have to know how each supported image stores the metadata and then count the bytes read... too error prone.